Nuxt 3 directive and updating component data
I made a directive because I would like to be able to detect when a mouse click was outside of a specific element. I will use this for a dropdown menu.
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('detect-click-outside', {
        mounted (el) {
            el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
                // // here I check that click was outside the el and his children
                if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                    // and if it did, change data from directive
                    console.log("click is inside")
                }

                console.log("click is outside")
                // update a value (name: clickedOutside) in the component
                // where this directive is used
            };

            document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
        },
    })
})

The problem I am facing, and unable to find an answer for on the internet, is how I can update "data" from the component in which the directive is used.
For example:
const clickedOutside = false;

When I click outside, the directive should update the above line in the component used. For example the "mainMenu" component.
Does anyone know how I can do that?
I can't find it in the Nuxt manual. For Vue it would be something like vnode.context.isDropdwonMenuVisible = false;, but for Nuxt 3 I am unable to find such a thing.
FYI I am using the <script setup> method in Nuxt.
Sample code of the menu:
<script setup>
const isDropdwonMenuVisible = ref(false);
</script>


<template>
  <div class="mx-auto max-w-screen-2xl flex border-b border-gray:50 py-4 text-sm" v-detect-click-outside>
    <div class="flex items-center text-lg font-bold cursor-pointer" v-for="(dataKey, dataIndex) in data" :keydata="dataIndex" @click="currentOpened = dataIndex">
      {{ dataIndex }} <img src="images/icons/chevron-down-solid.svg" width="12px" class="ml-4" />
    </div>
    {{ currentOpened }}
  </div>
</template>


I finally found it out. Quite dumb I didnt think about this before but oh well..
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('detect-click-outside', {
        mounted (el,binding, vnode) {
            el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
                if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                    console.log("click is outside")
                    binding.value(false);
                    return
                }

                console.log("click is inside")
                binding.value(true);
            };

            document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
        },
    })
})

That's the answer. In the template you simply do this:
<div v-detect-click-outside="test">Some content here</div>

And when you click outside, it will call a function called "test".
In that function you can then take the appropriate action.
const test = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
}

Works perfect in Nuxt 3.8.0
